# Extend page "width" or "margin" for todonotes comments or other package comments to sit in

Tags: margins, todonotes

Basically, I would like to know how to achieve margin/width extension, similar to what Word/OpenOffice does when users insert comments. I am using the `todonotes` package and am collaborating on a document, but because it is twin column the margins are too narrow and the notes become distorted, reducing their utility.

Comment: If you want to simply increase the width of the todonotes use `\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}`. If you want to increase the page layout, i.e. the borders left and right to the text you could use the `geometry` package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Does my comment address your issue? If yes, let me know and I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Jörg With no feedback, I think it would be best to make that an answer.

Comment: I had the same problem as the thread opener did. You comment did what I looked for. Would also vote for making it an answer. Maybe include reference to `geometry` package (`\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}`) for making the "content" smaller to allow space for the wider todo notes.

Comment: Could the inline-version of todonotes be a solution? That is, if you write your todo-notes as `\todo[inline]{}`, then they will be placed inline in the text rather than in the margins. It of course changes the layout, but might work in some cases.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to simply increase the width of the `todonotes`, use `\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}` in your preamble.

Maybe it could also be helpful to reduce the text size for the notes via a parameter on loading: `\usepackage[textsize=tiny]{todonotes}`

If you want to increase the page layout, i.e. the borders left and right to the text, you could load the `geometry` package and give appropriate options. For instance: `\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}`.

The `geometry` package is very powerful, so it's a good idea to have a look at the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf).

Comment: Sorry for not responding - this doesn't do what I need however.

Comment: in that way the todos are not shown fully

Answer (score 22):

I found that this works well if you want to make the paper wider while keeping the page layout unaffected (taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353914/15107)):

```
\paperwidth=\dimexpr \paperwidth + 6cm\relax
\oddsidemargin=\dimexpr\oddsidemargin + 3cm\relax
\evensidemargin=\dimexpr\evensidemargin + 3cm\relax
\marginparwidth=\dimexpr \marginparwidth + 3cm\relax
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Without these additions, we only see half of the notes, which are extending outside of the page.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! 
Worth noting that the first relax argument should be double the length of the 2nd-4th relax arguments. E.g. if you'd only like 2cm margins, first line use 4cm\relax, and 2cm\relax for the later lines.

Answer (score 1):

The paper length can also be increased using a similar command. This may be needed if a todonote is so large that it cuts off at the bottom end of the page.

```latex
\paperheight=\dimexpr \paperheight + 3cm\relax
```