# Widen page and margin while keeping other geometry settings

Tags: margins, geometry, todonotes

I repeatedly find myself in this situation:

- I write a paper with some publisher-specified layout (e.g. `acmart`, `IEEEtran`).
- I and my coauthors use `todonotes` to add notes to the margin while we draft the paper.
- The margins of those layouts are far too small.

What I then do is to manually recreate the publisher’s layout, but add a few centimeters to the paperwidth and the same amount to the marginwidth. This way,I have more space for the todonotes without affecting the layout of the actual content.

But it is annoying having to figure out the original dimensions first. Is there a some code that would effect these changes relative to the current page geometry?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
\paperwidth=\dimexpr \paperwidth + 6cm\relax
\oddsidemargin=\dimexpr\oddsidemargin + 3cm\relax
\evensidemargin=\dimexpr\evensidemargin + 3cm\relax
\marginparwidth=\dimexpr \marginparwidth + 3cm\relax
```